# Calculate number of zeros using the Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a hard time with calculating following task:
I need to calculate number of zeros of $f(z)=z^5+2z^3-z^2+2z+5$ on $\{z\in C: Rez>0, Imz>0\}$. I wanted to use quadrant of a circle lets call it $γ$. Then calculate the winding number of f(γ) around $0$ but I have trouble with figuring out who it will look like. I will be very gratefull for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is real and positive on $[0,+\infty)$, hence there is no change of argument on that part of the boundary of the quarter-disk. For large enough $R$, $f$ behaves essentially like $z \mapsto z^5$ on the circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$, so on the quarter-circle $Re^{it}$, $t \in \bigl[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]$, the argument changes by $\frac{5\pi}{2} + O(R^{-1})$. On the imaginary axis, we have

$$f(it) = (5 + t^2) + i(t^5 - 2 t^3 + 2t),$$

so everything stays in the right half-plane, and the argument changes from a little less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ at $iR$ (since $\arctan \frac{R^5 - 2R^3 + 2R}{R^2 + 5} = \frac{\pi}{2} - O(R^{-3})$) to $0 = \arg 5$ at $0$.

Since the total change of argument along the boundary must be a multiple of $2\pi$, it follows that the total change of argument here is exactly $2\pi$, hence there is precisely one zero in the quadrant $\operatorname{Re} z > 0,\, \operatorname{Im} z > 0$.